# Adding 'lang' query parameter to wordpress rest api call removes _embedded

Tags: json, wordpress, api, embed, wordpress-rest-api

In a multilanguage website I want to use the _embedded data of wordpress to get the featured image url.
This works fine in the (original) English request:
http://apistaging.fj-producties.mati.se/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed

But when I add the dutch language parameter the _embedded content disappears:
http://apistaging.fj-producties.mati.se/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&lang=nl

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Edit:
I use WPML to add the multiple language functionality, they add a parameter (lang=nl) to the Dutch pages & post requests

Comment: For any further help, you may precise what is your multilingual solution ?

Comment: I found a similar question on the WPML support site, the only suggestion there is that you update the plugin to latest version, but I guess you already tried that. https://wpml.org/forums/topic/problem-with-posts-rest-api/ It may be worth adding further information to that topic to see if you get an answer directly from WPML

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't solve my problem to update WPML, but I'll talk to them for further support. I'll add the solution here if I can find it. :)